# longtblr from tabularray not displayed properly in List of Tables

Tags: table-of-contents, tabularray

I have a few `longtblr` in my dissertation. They are displayed properly in the text body, however, in the List of Tables there are some issues (see figure attached): The captions are not displayed properly and the chapter number is missing.

[image]

I have tried enclosing the `longtblr` inside `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` and `\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}`, but then I get some errors. Any solutions?

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % This is to add section number before figure.

\begin{document}
    
\listoftables

\chapter{My Chapter 1}
Table \ref{tab:longtblrsample} is a long table created with tabularray.

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Sample table with tabularray},
    label={tab:longtblrsample},
    ]{width=\textwidth,
        colspec = {X[c,m] X[c,m]},
        rowhead = 1,
    }
    Number 1 & Number 2 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiling your MWE extended with one more chapter on `longtblr` tables gives expected results: tables are numbered as `<chapter>. <table>` and appear in LoT correctly. I tested with recent `tabularray` package: 2021Q

Comment: Any news? Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Zarko, thanks for taking the time to try to help me out but it worked itself out on its own. I formatted my computer and reinstalled MikTeX etc, and it seems to work now without making any changes (I had updated to the newest ```tabularray``` package before formatting and nothing changed). I figured the issue with the empty captions was because I added ```\label{tab:my_label}``` both before ```\end{tblr}``` and as an argument in ```\begin{tblr}[label={tab:my_label},]```. Sorry for taking so long to reply you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solve his problem with reinstall of MiKTeX and discover to us unknown and not shown errors in his code.

Answer (score 1):

I cant reproduce your problem. Considering my comment below your question, for test I used the following test MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small\sffamily}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries\sffamily}

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % This is to add section number before figure.
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\usepackage{lipsum} % fir dummy text in tables

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\chapter{My Chapter 1}
\section{first}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Standard table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
1   &   2   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:standardtable}
\end{table}
Table \ref{tab:standardtable} is standard table in \verb+table+ float. 

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Sample table with tabularray},
      label = {tab:longtblr},
    ]{hlines, vlines,
      colspec = {X[c,m] X[c,m]},
      rowhead = 1,
     }
    Number 1 & Number 2 \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
\end{longtblr}
Table \ref{tab:longtblr} is a long table created with \verb+longtblr+

\chapter{My Chapter 2}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Sample table with tabularray},
      label = {tab:longtblr-2},
    ]{hlines, vlines,
      colspec = {X[c,m] X[c,m]},
      rowhead = 1,
     }
    Number 1 & Number 2 \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
\end{longtblr}
Table \ref{tab:longtblr-2} is a long table created with \verb+longtblr+ in placed before first section in chapter. Observe \verb+0+ in caption as well in reference number.

\lipsum[1]

\section{First section in the second chapter}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {Sample of \texttt{talltblr} table with two lines long caption text which will not shown in the list of figures (LoF).},
      entry = {Short caption of \texttt{talltblr} table.},
      label = {tab:talltblr},
note{a} = {description of the first table note},
note{b} = {description of the second table note},
    ]{hlines, vlines,
      colspec = {X[c,m] X[c,m]},
      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
     }
Category\TblrNote{a} 
                & Reference\TblrNote{a}\\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \lipsum[66] & \lipsum[66]   \\
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
Table \ref{tab:talltblr} is a table created with \verb+tallgtblr+ placed in the first section in the second chapter. It is inserted in \verb+figure+ float, but caption is written as part of \verb+tallgtblr+ code.

\end{document}
```

It gives expected result: In LoT (ListofTables) are tables list equal for standard tables in `figure` environment and for `longtblr` tables:

[image]

**Edit:**
As you can see, both hasn't label name before table numbers. This is standard feature. If you like to add labels name before numbers, than you need to add in a document preamble the following code lines:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
  \cftsetindents{table}{0em}{6em}
  \renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
```

Considering them in my MWE gives:

[image]